# How to simplify the default implementation of a kotlin function

Tags: kotlin

> The following code, I always feel a bit long-winded.

```
//judging employee's salary level,  and set a default implemention of the function:whether it > amount
fun paidMore(amount: Int, employee: Employee,
     predicate: (Int, Employee) -> Boolean = { amount, employee -> employee.salary > amount }
): Boolean = predicate(amount, employee)
```

> I think I can simplify the code like this：

```
fun paidMore(amount: Int, employee: Employee, 
      predicate: (Int, Employee) -> Boolean = employee.salary > amount
): Boolean = predicate(amount, employee)
```

Of course, I am self-righteous. It can not run.

```
//This code is treated as a Boolean expression, not a function.
employee.salary > amount
```

> why? what should I do to simplify the code?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're having. What kind of simplification are you looking for?

Comment: There is no question here. One of the police will be along momentarily to tell you that and suggest closing this. You are asking for a code review. There is another SE for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Oh,yeah.I simplified a bit of code.

```
fun paidMore(amount: Int, employee: Employee,
                     predicate: (Int, Employee) -> Boolean = { _, _ -> employee.salary > amount }
        ): Boolean = predicate(amount, employee)
```

> now,I simplified the code again

```
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.describe
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.it
import kotlin.test.assertFalse
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

object ClosureSpec : Spek({
    describe("Test, add a default implementation to the function") {
        data class Employee(val name: String, val salary: Int) //the model used to test

        fun paidMore(amount: Int, employee: Employee,
                     predicate: (Int) -> Boolean = { _ -> employee.salary > amount }
        ): Boolean = predicate(amount)

        it("judging employee's salary level") {
            fun isHighPaid(employee: Employee): Boolean = paidMore(100, employee)
            fun isHighPaid2(employee: Employee): Boolean = paidMore(100, employee) {amount ->
                employee.salary > amount * 2
            }

            val employee = Employee("yuri", 101)
            assertTrue(isHighPaid(employee))
            assertFalse(isHighPaid2(employee))

            assertTrue(isHighPaid2(Employee("peter", 201)))
            assertFalse(isHighPaid2(Employee("jerry", 200)))
        }
    }

})
```

> or else

```
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.describe
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.it
import kotlin.test.assertFalse
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

object ClosureSpec : Spek({
    describe("Test, add a default implementation to the function") {
        data class Employee(val name: String, val salary: Int) //the model used to test

        //judging employee's salary level
        fun Employee.paidMore(amount: Int, predicate: (Int) -> Boolean = { 
            this.salary > it 
        }): Boolean = predicate(amount)

        on("use the default implementation") {
            val amount = 100
            fun Employee.isHighPaid() = paidMore(amount)

            it("should all be passed") {
                assertTrue(Employee("Alice", amount + 1).isHighPaid())
                assertFalse(Employee("Alice", amount - 1).isHighPaid())
            }
        }

        on("override the default implementation") {
            val amount = 100
            fun Employee.isHighPaid() = paidMore(amount) {
                this.salary > it * 2
            }

            it("should all be passed") {
                assertTrue(Employee("Bob", amount * 2 + 1).isHighPaid())
                assertFalse(Employee("Bob", amount * 2 - 1).isHighPaid())
            }
        }
    }
})
```

> Which one is better? something else? Looking forward to your good idea